# CSS pseudo element not working

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element, linear-gradients

I'm trying to create a gradient `border` underneath an image inside a `div`.

I'm 100% sure that my CSS code itself is perfectly fine as I've tested it on other elements before.

The problem is that somehow it refuses to select the correct element and place the pseudo element underneath it.

```css
#profilePicture {
  width: 200px;
  margin-left: 25px;
  border-top: 1px solid #070707;
  border-left: 1px solid #070707;
  border-right: 1px solid #070707;
}
#pf {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
}
#pf:first-child:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 1px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #070707, #a1a1a1, #070707);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #070707, #a1a1a1, #070707);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #070707, #a1a1a1, #070707);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #070707, #a1a1a1, #070707);
  top: -1px;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="profilePicture">
  <img id="pf" src="layout/images/profile/pf.png">
</div>
```

As far as I can tell it's supposed to select `#pf` which is the first child of its parent (true) and add the pseudo element after it?

**Edit:** I did try `top: 1px` and greater **height**s to be sure. This had no effect.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/::after , states that ::after matches the last virtual child of an element. As far as I am aware `img` can have no children. Also look at Gradient Borders: https://css-tricks.com/examples/GradientBorder/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use pseudo elements (`::before` and `::after`) in `img` tag (at least for now).

See what [W3C specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#before-after-content) says:

> Note. This specification does not fully define the interaction of `:before` and `:after` with replaced elements (such as `IMG` in HTML). This will be defined in more detail in a future specification.

So you have to apply the pseudo element to the parent instead.

Also you need to use `position:relative` in the parent because you are applying `position:absolute` in pseudo element. With that you will keep the pseudo element in the flow with the DOM.

Note there is a few changes in your CSS

```css
body {
  margin: 0
}
#profilePicture {
  width: 200px;
  margin-left: 25px;
  position: relative;
  border: solid #070707;
  border-width: 1px 1px 0 1px
}
#pf {
  display: block;
}
#profilePicture::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 5px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #070707, #a1a1a1, #070707);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #070707, #a1a1a1, #070707);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #070707, #a1a1a1, #070707);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #070707, #a1a1a1, #070707);
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="profilePicture">
  <img id="pf" src="//dummyimage.com/200x200&text=image">
</div>
```

Comment: yes, only the `position:relative` missing, he need to understand how `position:absolute` work.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's working as expected. I already knew about `position:relative` I simply forgot it (Doh!). I'm gonna accept your answer as it explains the problem in more detail for future readers.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use pseudo elements (`:before` and `:after`) with `img` tag, create extra `div` around `img` or add `:after` to your `#profilePicture` element instead.

Also there is no reason of using `first-child` in `#pf:first-child:after` selector since only one element with `pf` id can be on the page.

Edit:

1. Add `position: relative` to your `#profilePicture`
2. Remove `top: 1px;` from `:after`
3. Add `bottom: 0;` to `:after`

Comment: I honestly believe that this is supposed to work, but somehow it keeps adding the pseudo element above the div. I've tried adding an extra div as well as using `#profilePicture` instead. But both give the same result.

Comment: Yes. But this is what I'm getting: [http://www.icecub.nl/test/result.png](http://www.icecub.nl/test/result.png)

Comment: I've udated my answer, please confirm it's working for you now

Answer (score 0):

Just add `position:relative` for this selector `#profilePicture`, and change the `#profilePicture::after` to:

```css
#profilePicture::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 1px;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #070707, #a1a1a1, #070707);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #070707, #a1a1a1, #070707);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #070707, #a1a1a1, #070707);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #070707, #a1a1a1, #070707);
    bottom: 1px;
    left: 0;
}
```